# Two browsers are open in parallel, I have to access hover element in one browser

Tags: protractor

I'm facing an issue in finding the hidden element.

I have to open my older version login page to access all the elements of my newer version (Live data), but when I'm trying to access the hover element in the newer version in Firefox I'm getting Element not visible error since the login page of older version still open. If I close the older version page, I can't access the newer version with all the elements.

I am trying this code,I can click the open button

```
   describe('Testing the template sorting ', function()    
   {                                       
   beforeEach(function() {

    browser.get('http:localhost:port/#/project/project0  /sites');

    });

    it('should check hover tiles open function', function() { 

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         var elm = element.all(by.buttonText('Open')).get(i);
            browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform();
                        elm.click();
       element.all(by.css(".ng-isolate-scope i")).get(1).click();
    }
    });
    });
      But If I try the same code with this login operation,it is failing.



     describe('view old version Home page and to do testing', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {     
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
          browser.get('http:olderversion localhost');
       });

    it('should login to  olderversion',function() {
            element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('xxxxxx');
      element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('xxxxxx');
    browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iw_option']
    /tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/a")).click();

     });
     });



     describe('Testing the hover tile buttons ', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('http:localhost:port/#/project/Test1_Project /sites');
                });

     it('should check hover tiles open function', function() {              

                  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                   {
                var elm = element.all(by.buttonText('Open')).get(1);

                browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).perform();
                elm.click();                        
         element.all(by.css(".ng-isolate-
       copei")).get(1).click();                        
           }             
     });
    });

I get the following error,.Please suggest me to resolve this
ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be
interacted with
 Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-2       
System info: host: 'SARVABAT1', ip: 'xxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.ar
ch: 'xxxx', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have luck with browser.switchTo() or browser.driver.switchTo(), depending on if angular is present.

I haven't done it before, buy it may look something like:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
  oldWindow = handles[1];
  newWindow = handles[0];
  browser.driver.switchTo().window(newWindow).getWindowHandle();
  doStuffWithNewElements();
});
```

See if that gets you a bit closer!